# How to set a max scroll height?

Tags: html, css

I have made a website which includes a chatbox. The main text Area has a height of 700px and a scrollbar. Is there a way to limit the scroll height because now the chat is endless if i run the website for a longer period of time. So basicly what i want is that the messages get deleted when they are out of the max scroll height. I hope you can understand my problem. Thanks

```
<div id="textArea"></div>

<style type="text/css">

#textArea{
  width:220px;
  height:70%;
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  top:38px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  color:#fefefe;
} 

</style>
```

Comment: Not sure how to accomplish that, but for what it's worth it would be a lot better to remove old messages from the HTML document with JavaScript, than hide it.

Comment: How are you updating the messages? Couldn't you just remove old ones from the dataset? That would keep the container to a minimal size.

Comment: ok ty i'll try that

Comment: how do i delete the first messages with jquery? nothing seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to set the `overflow-y:` to `auto` and, using JavaScript or JQuery, make the messages disappear after they reach a certain height in pixels.